# Does the dealer need to inmediately count the chips after a player goes all-in?

Tags: rules, casino

When a player goes all-in, can the dealer wait to see if any player calls to evitate to need to count if nobody calls?

Or he should inmediately count the amount of the bet to inform the other players how much chips should they put on the table to see or raise the all-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no, unless asked the dealer shouldn't touch or count the chips. While not a hard rule or anything from what I can recall, it's better to just wait until asked. Some players like  to use speech play and interact with the all-in player. I've seen some players get very upset when a dealer has just dived into counting the chips.

It's not a hard rule from what I can remember, more so just giving the players an opportunity to play their game how they want. Some players will just ask for a count straight away and in which case just dive in and count it out. Just remember though some casinos have house-rules and yours may have a rule that requires it to be counted out. Just check if unsure with the cardroom or casino.

It's also potentially time saving for the game. An example of this, Player A goes all-in for a lot, Player asks how much is that, before the dealer can reach for the chips, Player A says some big number, Player B just instantly mucks.

Comment: Yes, in my experience in the US, dealers are trained to wait for a request.

Comment: Same for us in Europe from when I was a dealer

Comment: Same here, dealer are not to count unless asked. I get a little dismayed at dealers that call out bet sizes, stack bets and the like without being asked. It distracts the dealer a bit, and I can count chips pretty well, I think it is an advantage and do not appreciate when that advantage is neutralized.

Comment: Completely agree @Jon. Everytime I see it happen I internally scream a little :D